# Can I randomize Joomla/K2 article URLs?

Tags: joomla, joomla-k2, joomla-article

I am looking for a way to add a random string/value to all Joomla article URLs. The reason for this is that people will be able to access URLs provided they have the link to the content however they should not be able to get at other content by substituting the article id in the URL (i.e: index.php/category/1, index.php/category/2).

Regardless of alias text placing the article id onto the url with url rewriting enabled will access the article. I am using the K2 component so would be applying this to K2 articles (Items).

I had thought about hard coding the alias to a random value on article creation but this won't solve the issue. Even a way of obfuscating the URL should work, although the plugins I tried for Joomla only do external links.

//Software: Joomla 2.5/K2 2.5/Apache server

Comment: Why would you want to do this?  If you want to restrict access, you can use Joomla's ACL to control access.

Comment: I am aware of the Joomla ACL. It is a system that uses QR codes for the URLS, the URLs will be accessible only by the people with the QR Code. It is similar to what the file hosting sites do, randomize the URL so only the people with it can access the content. It's not a file hosting site, just one for data retrieval. It is not going to production, so the quality of the site/how the functionality is implemented does not have to be perfect.